# How to control how long Google Assistant keeps listening when there is silence?

Tags: text-to-speech, google-assistant, voice-recording

I'm using Google Assistant to take notes on my phone via my bluetooth headset.  However, when I'm taking a note, if I don't talk for about 1.5 seconds, it immediately asks me if I want to save the note using Keep, even though I'm (sometimes) not done with the note yet!

This is unfortunate, because I have time it, and from the point I tap my headset and go through all the (voice) steps to start recording until I can actually start dictating my note a minimum of 13 seconds have passed.  This extra delay means I have to keep in my head exactly what I was going to say for at least that long, while remembering the things to say to get it to start recording.

As a workaround, I tried just continuously talking.  However, after just under a minute of talking (speaking numbers at a rate of about one per second) it stopped automatically to save the note and I found it had transcribed only 55 numbers.

Update: It's okay if Google Assistant stops and saves my current note, as long as it keeps listening for additional commands from Bluetooth.  Currently, it seems like as soon as the note is finished it stops listening and I have to start all over again.

Comment: @beeshyams no, it's a Nexus 6p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Google help](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0oqXxIOVCbWg)

> There isn't any way at this time to force the microphone to stay on for Voice Typing. When you pause for several seconds, voice typing assumes you're taking a break. This likely helps to conserve your device's battery as well

I haven't found any workaround on XDA .

So, I guess sending Google feedback is the only way out for now